# Why is text about deleted answer comments an anchor element?

Tags: bug, design, deleted-answers

A few days ago I deleted an answer and accidentally hovered over the text:

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

To my surprise, the style of the text changed and made me believe that clicking on that text will redirect me to some page.

[image: comment]

I clicked on the text and nothing happened. After inspecting the element, it turns out that it was an anchor element with no `href` attribute nor on-click event handler attached, which doesn't seem to do anything. I guess this should be a regular text with a tooltip, similarly to reputation score and badges count below a user's nickname.

Comment: It re-uses the add comment link and the behavior is the same on [locked posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c). fixing the cursor can be done on the disabled-link css rule. That will still leave the hover for links. Removing the anchor adds complexity at render time for little gain.